# How to use the function tf.metrics.sensitivity_at_specificity in tensorflow? And how to set the required_arg specificity in the functiuon?

Tags: tensorflow

how to use the function:

```
tf.metrics.sensitivity_at_specificity(
    labels,
    predictions,
    specificity,
    weights=None,
    num_thresholds=200,
    metrics_collections=None,
    updates_collections=None,
    name=None
)
```

Comment: @xzI97 Welcome to StackOverflow. Without question we find an increase in our questions clarity and community acceptance and response by including a functional example, here's a link on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, it's always beneficial to understand a communities purpose and features which is quick and easy to review by completing the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I've worked it out.